# document.querySelector issues

Tags: javascript, html

In the following code, why is document.querySelector() returning null?

```
var element = document.createElement('div');
element.classList.add('abc');
var test = document.querySelector("." + element.className);
```

Comment: element is not added to dom yet.

Comment: I think that you should have document.querySelector("div .abc");

Comment: Also I would expect you to need `var test = document.querySelector("."+element.className);`

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a `.`

```
var test = document.querySelector("."+element.className);
```

EDIT

You also need to add it to body

```
document.body.appendChild(element);
```

See http://codepen.io/jammer99/pen/dMmXYL

Answer (score 2):

1. The div is not part of the DOM until you append it to a DOM element.
2. You need to add a dot in front to use the querySelector on a class string: `document.querySelector("."+element.className)`
3. The DOM element you append your div to has to exist before you can access it.

```js
window.onload=function() { // body exists
  var element = document.createElement('div');
  element.classList.add('abc');
  var test = document.querySelector("."+element.className);
  console.log(test,element.className);
  document.body.appendChild(element); // NOW the DIV exists in DOM
  test = document.querySelector("."+element.className);
  console.log(test);
}
```